# Symfony Form: OneToMany and CollectionType Field

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I got stucked into building a form with Symfony 3.

I defined an entity 'News' containing an attribute 'newsArticle', which has a OneToMany Relation to the entity 'NewsArticle', holding translations of its attributes 'headline', 'subheader and 'bodytext'.
The goal is to provide a form that holds on the one hand fields for the attributes of 'News' and on the other hand fields to create an 'NewsArticle' entry for the default language.

Entity News (excerpt):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news")
 */
class News {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsArticle", mappedBy="news", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $newsArticle;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->newsArticle = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Entity NewsArticle (excerpt):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_article")
 */
class NewsArticle {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $news;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=false, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $headline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subheadline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=65536, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $bodytext;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $languageId;
}
```

The Controller (excerpt):

```
public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $lang = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('Bundle:Language')
        ->findOneBy(array('deleted' => 0, 'fallback' => 1));

    $news = new News();
    //$news->newsArticle->setLanguageId($lang);

    $form = $this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($news);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:News:add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'news' => $news,
    ));
}
```

TWIG Template (excerpt):

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.headline) }}
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            {{ form_errors(form.headline) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.headline) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.subheadline) }}
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            {{ form_errors(form.subheadline) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.subheadline) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.bodytext) }}
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            {{ form_errors(form.bodytext) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.bodytext) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

NewsType (excerpt):

```
class NewsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('newsArticle', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => NewsArticleType::class,
                'allow_add'   => true,
                'allow_delete'   => true,
            ))
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\News',
        ));
    }
}
```

NewsArticleType (excerpt):

```
class NewsArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('headline', TextType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('subheadline', TextType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('bodytext', CKEditorType::class, array(
                'required' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\NewsArticle',
        ));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error message...

> Neither the property "headline" nor one of the methods "headline()", "getheadline()"/"isheadline()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" in Bundle:_Partials:Form/news.html.twig at line 27

... and have no idea, how to access the attributes of the related entity? Any hints?

*EDIT #1:*

The complete 'Child'-Entity including getters/ setters:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_article")
 */
class NewsArticle {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="newsArticle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $news;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=false, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $headline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subheadline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=65536, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $bodytext;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $languageId;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set headline
     *
     * @param string $headline
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setHeadline($headline)
    {
        $this->headline = $headline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get headline
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeadline()
    {
        return $this->headline;
    }

    /**
     * Set subheadline
     *
     * @param string $subheadline
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setSubheadline($subheadline)
    {
        $this->subheadline = $subheadline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subheadline
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSubheadline()
    {
        return $this->subheadline;
    }

    /**
     * Set bodytext
     *
     * @param string $bodytext
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setBodytext($bodytext)
    {
        $this->bodytext = $bodytext;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bodytext
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBodytext()
    {
        return $this->bodytext;
    }

    /**
     * Set news
     *
     * @param \Bundle\Entity\News $news
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setNews(\Bundle\Entity\News $news = null)
    {
        $this->news = $news;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get news
     *
     * @return \Bundle\Entity\News
     */
    public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->news;
    }

    /**
     * Set languageId
     *
     * @param \Bundle\Entity\Language $languageId
     *
     * @return NewsArticle
     */
    public function setLanguageId(\Bundle\Entity\Language $languageId = null)
    {
        $this->languageId = $languageId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get languageId
     *
     * @return \Bundle\Entity\Language
     */
    public function getLanguageId()
    {
        return $this->languageId;
    }
}
```

The getters and setters for the attributes exist, but I wonder why the error message misses the method **get*h*eadline()** instead of **get*H*eadline()**? Could it be, the problem is a wrong syntax in the TWIG: {{ form_errors(form.headline) }} ? I've tried {{ form_errors(form.newsArticle.headline) }} too, but the error message remains the same.

Any hints, please?

Comment: Read up a bit about private/protected and public attributes:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php.  Once you understand it the need for getters/setters will become obvious.  Might also want to take a look in the Symfony docs.  Plenty of examples on using entities and forms.

Comment: Even if I set all attributes of the child entity NewsArticle to public I get the same error message. I´ve read the Symfony Docs, especially the Chapter regarding FormTypes, but unfortuantely there´s no example for this kind of nested forms. It´s only mentioned that the CollectionType would do the job: "In more complex examples, you can embed entire forms, which is useful when creating forms that expose one-to-many relationships" (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Comment: Did you read the cookbook? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Yes I did, but it´s not helpful in this case. I didn´t find a similar example yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem just setters getters

As you try this command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities youBundle
```

for generate getter/setter or write it

And you forgot inversedBy in you entity NewsActicle

like this :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="newsArticle" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $news;
```

Comment: Right, I´m using the console command doctrine:generate:entities to generate getters and setters. Thanks for the hint to add 'inversedBy' - unfortunately the error message remains :( I`ll post the getters/ setters in the hope your guess points to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After all I made some progress and got rid of the eror message.

One problem in my TWIG was that *$newsArticle* is an array of objects and not an object, so I need to iterate the array first:

```
{% for newsArticle in form.newsArticle %}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(newsArticle.headline) }}
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        {{ form_errors(newsArticle.headline) }}
        {{ form_widget(newsArticle.headline) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(newsArticle.subheadline) }}
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        {{ form_errors(newsArticle.subheadline) }}
        {{ form_widget(newsArticle.subheadline) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(newsArticle.bodytext) }}
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        {{ form_errors(newsArticle.bodytext) }}
        {{ form_widget(newsArticle.bodytext) }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Another important change was to instantiate the NewsArticle object first in the NewsController:

```
public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $lang = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('Bundle:Language')
        ->findOneBy(array('deleted' => 0, 'fallback' => 1));

    $article = new NewsArticle();
    $article->setLanguageId($lang);

    $news = new News();
    $news->setPublic(0);
    $news->setDeleted(0);
    $news->setIdent($hash);
    $news->getNewsArticle()->add($article);


    $form = $this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($news);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'Your changes were saved!'
        );
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:News:add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'news' => $news,
    ));
}
```

I don´t think this is the best solution (particulary iterating an array which only has one object), but at least I don´t get the error message and it seems to work for the moment. 
If you´ve got an idea for improvement, pleas let me know - I would appreciate your help a lot!